# How to restrict if condition only one time execution in java

Tags: java

The `if`-condition checks every value in my code, but I want it to only execute once; that's enough.

Here is my code:

```
Session session = null;
try{
    Query qu = session.createSQLQuery("select plot_no from house_details where type='duplex'");
    List<Long> li =  qu.list();
    System.out.println("---li---"+li.toString());
    for (Iterator itr = li.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        String plotNo = itr.next().toString();

        if(plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"){
            System.out.println("---if---");
            //code here
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("---else---");
            Query qu1 = session.createSQLQuery("select distinct name, houseno from house_details");
            List li1 =  qu1.list();
            for (Iterator itr1 = li.iterator(); itr1.hasNext();) {
                Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr1.next();
                String houseName = (String) obj[0];
                String houseNo = (String) obj[1];
                System.out.println("---houseName--->"+houseName);
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(session != null){
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
---li---[501, 501, 0, 101, 520,601,601, 101, 114]
```

In my output the **`if`**-condition checks **501** two times, **520** one time and **601** two times, so it totally executes the `if`-condition **five** times. I want it to only execute the **`if`** once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `flag` and make it false first time when if statement is executed. And do like below.

```
if(flag)
if(plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"){
        flag = false;
        System.out.println("---if---");
        //code here
    }
```

Hope it clears.

Comment: where is it place **false**, i mean starting position

Comment: Initialize it as true at start. Then it will only execute once.

Comment: i placed **boolean flag = false** before for loop,it is correct or not

Comment: place flag = true before for loop.

Comment: Thank You it's working fine thank you so much @FallAndLearn

Comment: same proccess how to apply in **else**

Comment: You have if and else statements in for loop. Else will always be executed if if statement is not executed. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: 501,520,601 these three values checked in **if** condition,remaining values checked in **else** condition for example i have ten values so ten times going in **else** condition,so here also once checked **else** after process is stop it.As same as **if** condition

Answer (score 1):

You can us boolean variable to check particular condition.
For example

```
boolean is501 = false;
boolean is520 = false;
boolean is601 = false;

//You need to define is501 this outside of for loop

if(plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601"){
   if (!is501 && plotNo.equals("501")) {
     //Your logic
     is501 = true;
   }
   else if (!is520 && plotNo.equals("520")) {
     //Your logic
     is520 = true;
   }
   else if (!is520 && plotNo.equals("601")) {
     //Your logic
     is601 = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can add the same condition for others.

Comment: i tried this way **if(!is501 && plotNo.equals("501") || plotNo.equals("520") || plotNo.equals("601")**  but not working

Comment: i my logic so many **sql queries** is there,so three **if** conditions execute at a time?